# Update istio-ingressgateway with yaml instead of kubectl edit

Tags: yaml, kubectl, istio

I test tcp-based service from book...

To complete this task, I need to expose port 31400...

I found that I can do this using this command : KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system

and enter manually this :

- name: tcp
  nodePort: 30851
  port: 31400,
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 31400

I work as expected, but how do the same task using yaml and kubectl apply ?

Thanks for your help,

WCDR

Comment: How did you install istio? Did you use any helm charts or directly installed using istioctl?

Comment: I work on Ubuntu 20 with Minikube : knative Serving v1.3.0 & Eventing v1.3.1 / Istio install : 

 curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.12.5 sh - ;
 cd istio-1.12.5 ;
 export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH ;
 istioctl install --set profile=default -y /

Tools install : 

 kubectl apply -f samples/addons/prometheus.yaml ;
 kubectl apply -f samples/addons/grafana.yaml ;
 kubectl apply -f samples/addons/jaeger.yaml ;
 kubectl apply -f samples/addons/kiali.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Get current configuration :

```
$ kubectl get -n istio-system service istio-ingressgateway -o yaml
```

Output look like :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {...,"kind":"Service",..."app":"istio-ingressgateway"...
  ...
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    ...
    spec:
    ...
    ports:
     ...
     >>>> insert block here <<<<
    selector:
    ...
...
```

2 - Patch it with yq or manually...

```
https://github.com/mikefarah/yq
```

3 - Apply change :

```
 $ kubectl apply -n istio-system -f - <<EOF
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    ...
    EOF
```

Output must be :

```
service/istio-ingressgateway configured
```

Enjoy...

Comment: This will definitely work. Incase someone is using  gateway helm charts for installing ingress gateway, they can apply the same config in values.yaml file.